# Firebase Security - Shared Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am getting confused about Firebase Security. Here why...

For example; I have the following database:

```
clients: {
    $key: {
        //client data
    }
}

trainer: {
    $key: {
        //trainer data
    }
}
```

I need a client to be able to see their own information. I need a trainer to be able to see the information of all their clients, but not other trainers.

So client A, B and C can see their personal, private data. But Trainer A can only see client A and B's details (he doesn't train C).

The problem I run into is that you can't seem to request for example all clients, but only return the ones that checkout with security rules. As the docs state, if one in the list returns false, the whole bunch does.

How can I create the correct structure and security rules?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to examples in the Firebase docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security), this might work for you.

I think at a minimum your structure could benefit from having a direct key tie between client and trainer. Something like

```
clients: {
   clientA: {
       trainerKey: "trainerA"
   }
}

trainers: {
   trainerA: {
      clients: { clientA: true, clientB: true }
   }
}
```

**Security Rules - edited to include user**

```
"clients": {
    ".read": "auth !== null && (root.child('trainers/' + $trainerKey + '/clients').child($uid).exists() || auth.uid == $uid")
}
```

This a) checks that a user is authenticated and b) looks to see if the client is in the list of clients for the trainer OR whether this is the client.

This is untested, but hopefully gets you where you're trying to go. I'm also making the assumption that your clients IDs are the same as their auth ID.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried something almost the same as this, but will give it a go. Surely this would fail if there is a client that `trainerA` doesn't have? If the rule returns false on any check, the whole result is nil, right?

Comment: Yes, it should. This is untested, so it may not work in its current state for your case. That said, should get you close to what you need, conceptually, at the very least.

Comment: I appreciate the idea. How can I possibly request all data at `clients` and it just return those that pass security though?

Comment: If I'm thinking about this correctly, you're authenticated as a trainer, and you only care about the clients that are yours. Why would you need to pull all clients (think about your app as it scales) rather than the clients that you know already are tied to the trainer?

Comment: Well the only reason I say this is if I put all of the trainers clients under that trainer in the database, then the clients are locked out from viewing their personal data. Which is why I thought to keep all clients under one node, perhaps the wrong approach?

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll edit, because I think I know what you need.

Comment: Also, I think keeping all clients under one node is the correct approach, while also having a key to each client under trainers and vice versa. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You should impliment something  like adding clients to trainer as friend.  Create a node sharedwith which contains trainer  as child and trainer will contains  A & B clients key and their data .

Comment: Thanks for your response. Won't this end with lots of duplicate data though?

Comment: Duplicating data will be an easy approach and thats what firebase engineer  also suggested.  You should look at  json file of example chat app provide by firebase. Duplication  keeps data denormalize , rather  than keeping lots of data inside a single node which will take time to load  and will affect real time performance  of your app